# Prevent short comments from wrapping in R Markdown/knitr output

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

Is it possible to get a code chunk `tidy`ed up, while leaving the comments alone?

Say I wanna put ASCII art in some comments in a function, I could just set `tidy = F` but then the rest of the code chunk is "messy" as in the following output:

```
myfun=function(a,b){
  ##     ^_^
  ##    {o,o}
  ##    |)__)
  ##-----m-m-----
  c=sum(a,b)
  return(c) 
}
```

If I set `tidy = T` then the short comments all wrap together and I get the following as output:

```
myfun = function(a, b) {
    ## ^_^ {o,o} |)__) -----m-m-----
    c = sum(a, b)
    return(c)
}
```

What I would like to see is the following as output:

```
myfun = function(a, b) {
    ##      ^_^
    ##     {o,o} 
    ##     |)__)
    ## -----m-m-----
    c = sum(a, b)
    return(c)
}
```

Comment: OK. I figured it out. It's mentioned [here](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/wiki) that roxygen comments (`#'`) will not be wrapped in any case.  Moderators, should I delete this question since I answered it myself after finishing the research I should have done before posting?

Comment: also consider the `txtplot` package, if you want matching graphics style in the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I'll answer my own question.

If one looks at Yihui's [documentation for `formatR`](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/wiki), one might notice that roxygen comments (which look like this: `#'`) will not be wrapped in any case.

So using the code chunk

````
```{r, tidy = T}
myfun=function(a,b){
  #'     ^_^
  #'    {o,o}
  #'    |)__)
  #'-----m-m-----
  c=sum(a,b)
  return(c)
}
```
````

will give me the desired output:

```
myfun = function(a, b) {
    #'     ^_^
    #'    {o,o}
    #'    |)__)
    #'-----m-m-----
    c = sum(a, b)
    return(c)
}
```